# Error on npm installl node-icu-charset-detector

Tags: node.js, irc, node-gyp, rebuild

I have IRC on my project, which depends on node-icu-charset-detector.
When I do npm install

> node-icu-charset-detector@0.2.0 install C:\xampp\htdocs\ootify-be\node_modules\node-icu-charset-detector
>   node-gyp rebuild

it's throwing an error

> c:\myProj\node_modules\node-icu-charset-detector\node-icu-charset-detector.cpp(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unicode/ucsdet.h': No such file or directory [C:\myProj\node_modules\node-icu-charset-detector\build\node-
>   icu-charset-detector.vcxproj]
>   gyp ERR! build error
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.9.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
>   gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.9.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
>   gyp ERR! cwd C:\myProj\node_modules\node-icu-charset-detector
>   gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
>   gyp ERR! not ok

this is from package-lock.json

```
"irc": {
      "version": "0.5.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/irc/-/irc-0.5.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-NxT0doNlqW0LL3dryRFmvrJGS7w=",
      "requires": {
        "iconv": "2.2.3",
        "irc-colors": "1.4.2",
        "node-icu-charset-detector": "0.2.0"
      }
    },
```

I try a lot of things which I found by searching, but nothings help

Comment: can you share package.json

Comment: which part of my package.json interested?